# Multiple filters in list comprehension in Erlang

Tags: erlang

Say I have a list that contains weather:

```
1> Weather = [{toronto, rain}, {montreal, storms}, {london, fog}, 
    {paris, sun}, {boston, fog}, {vancouver, snow}].
```

To get foggy places, I could do this:

```
2> FoggyPlaces = [X || {X, fog} <- Weather].
[london,boston]
```

Now I want to retrieve places that are both foggy and snowy. I tried this, but it retrieves only snowy places,

```
3> FoggyAndSnowyPlaces = [X || {X, fog} <- Weather, {X,snow} <- Weather].
[vancouver,vancouver]
```

where I was expecting `[london,boston,vancouver]`.

How can I include multiple filters?

Comment: Also in comprehensions the variables in patterns are always new fresh variables which shadow variables with the same name. So there is no implicit matching of the `X`s.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
FoggyAndSnowyPlaces = [X || {X, Y} <- Weather, (Y == fog) or (Y == snow)].
```

You are confusing *generators* (`Pattern <- List`) and *filters* (boolean conditions). Multiple generators work like nested loops in other languages, so in your `3>` you get `vancouver` twice because the first generator produces two values.

Comment: I only mentioned filters because `{X,fog}` pattern is said to act as a filter to retrieve foggy places. So, in that sense I wanted to know if it is possible to create a new list based on multiple weather matches.

Comment: After two hours of thinking, the fog over my head is finally clearing, I think. Thank you.